# How to find the $k$th derivative of $1/x^y$ with respect to $x$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

What would be the solution to the $k^{th}$ derivative of the following function

$$\dfrac{1}{x^y}$$
With respect to $x$ where y is a constant.

I have calculated the first derivative
$$-y\dfrac{1}{x^{y+1}}$$
and the second
$$y(y+1)\dfrac{1}{x^{y+2}}$$
third
$$-y(y+1)(y+2)\dfrac{1}{x^{y+3}}$$
fourth
$$y(y+1)(y+2)(y+3)\dfrac{1}{x^{y+4}}$$

Therefore the nth derivative is 
$$(-1)^n (?) \dfrac{1}{x^{y+n}} $$

I cannot seem to spot the patten and cannot get the $k^{th}$ derivative.

Comment: is $y$ an integer?

Comment: It might help to recall that $\frac{1}{x^y}=x^{-y}$, which may aid in both taking derivatives and finding a general formula.

Comment: hint: calculate the 3rd, 4th, and 5th derivatives too.

Comment: I also see $(-1)^n$ and $x^{-(y+n)}$ but im struggling with y(y+1)(y+2)

Comment: I am really stuck :(

Comment: If y is an integer, $$(-1)^n\binom{y+(k-1)}{k}\frac{1}{x^{y+k}}$$

Comment: Apologies for my misunderstanding but can you re-write this in a simpler form.

Comment: Another writing: $(-1)^ny^{\overline k}\frac{1}{x^{y+k}}$, where $y^\overline{k}$ is the rising factorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \begin{align}  \displaystyle \frac{\partial^k}{\partial x^k} \frac 1{x^y} &= (-1)^k \displaystyle \frac {(y + (k - 1))!}{(y-1)!} \displaystyle \frac 1{x^{y+k}} \\ &= (-1)^k \binom{y + (k-1)}{k} k! \displaystyle \frac 1{x^{y+k}}  , \text{where } k = 1, 2, 3, ... \end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you very much, i tried 1/x in the same way and got $$ 1/x^{k+1}$$, is this correct?

Comment: The k-th derivative of $\displaystyle \frac {1}{x}$? That would be the same as for $\displaystyle \frac {1}{x^y}, \text{where } y = 1.$

Comment: Making it $$(-1)^k*k!\dfrac{1}{x^{k+1}}$$
Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.